# Mac keeps corrupting my AppleScripts

Tags: applescript

At first, I thought it was a Google Drive synch issue, so I copied the script out of Google Drive to my home folder.

The script runs automatically via an `osascript` command line call. All seems fine for days, sometimes weeks, but eventually the script stops working and when I open it, it's just gibberish.

What could be causing the script to become corrupted and how do I prevent it from happening again?

In the meantime, I copied the contents of the script to a text based file and saved it with a `.osa` extension to hopefully keep it from getting corrupted that way.

But how can I discover what is causing the corruption?

*MORE DETAILS* (as requested)

Multiple scripts are getting corrupted, but the one that I'm dealing with ATM is one I put up in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/hepcat72/6b7abd9000e8b108ecdb76e12da1257e/e4405398a1236b5d9bc8be40de228ceb1aeffd93) (the second revision) and is called sendText.scpt. The gist version is the .osa version.  I changed the automated run of the original `.scpt` version to use the `.osa` version instead, which I hope will avoid this corruption issue.

The corrupted file, when opened in Script Editor starts out looking like this:

[image: top of corrupted script]

Interestingly in this case, the corrupted `sendText.scpt` file changes into a directory named `sendText` and inside that folder is a file (oddly) named `sentText.scpt`.  I think that that file name was originally a typo that I fixed later to be `sendText.scpt`.

And to answer another question, I copied the script (originally in a google drive folder) right into my home folder.

Lastly, for this particular script, I run it automatically using node red in an exec node, which, like I said, can run numerous times for weeks on end without a problem.  I use this particular script to send myself messages about my automations.  It runs on average about a dozen times a day.

Comment: What OS version? What does the script do? Can you post the original and the corrupted versions of the script here? Where in your home folder is the script? What is the 'osascript command line call'?

Comment: Try using Command-I on the AppleScript file to lock it from being modified. Or use a `chmod` command in Terminal to lock it as well, with more granular control of who can modify it.

Comment: It's multiple scripts that this is happening to actually, but the one I'm dealing with now is in a gist here: https://gist.github.com/hepcat72/6b7abd9000e8b108ecdb76e12da1257e And I'm on Monterey 12.4. I'll update my question with a sample of the gibberish and some details for that specific case.

Comment: That looks like a compiled script when you open it in TextEdit, so perhaps something is formatting the null/control/non-ASCII characters or expecting different data or encoding for the files.  In the mean time, you might want to just stick with text versions of the script (which normally have an`.applescript` extension).

Comment: I similarly thought it had to do with the encoding - like the script editor and the interpreter incorrectly assume it's a text file and not (binary?) encoded, thus it displays as gibberish and will not run. If this is simply a bad resource fork and the compiled code is intact, I assume it's a problem with the resource fork. Is there a way to "repair" that? I can certainly leave it as text since I still have the source code, but if recovering that is ever a problem, it would be good to know how to fix it. I wonder if the osascript executable could be causing this damage...

Comment: The resource fork has some symbols in it, but removing the attribute won’t change the script (don’t know about just corrupting it).  Another thing to consider is that properties and global variables (even those in the run handlers) are saved in the script file when run (including via `osascript`), although I don’t see anything obvious in your gist.  Similar to making a script read-only, this doesn’t happen with a text file, since it is compiled when used.

Comment: To what attribute are you referring? The file type? I actually know very little about resource forks (not much stuck anyway - I just never used that knowledge and it got hazy over time).

Comment: Incidentally, the revision that this last happened to is: https://gist.github.com/hepcat72/6b7abd9000e8b108ecdb76e12da1257e/e4405398a1236b5d9bc8be40de228ceb1aeffd93  I'll update the link in the question so it's apples to apples.

Comment: I was referring to the `com.apple.ResourceFork` extended attribute - from the Terminal, you can use `xattr -plx com.apple.ResourceFork /path/to/your.scpt` to see it (dragging from a Finder window will paste an escaped path).